# Два Transparent обьекта

Tags: unity3d, render

Есть сфера и спрайт внутри сферы и оба Transparent.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку Transparent нет в Z-Buffer, тупо считается расстояние до камеры и eсли, отодвинуть спрайт дальше от центра сферы относительно камеры спрайт исчезнет.

Есть варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если URP рассматривается, то можно использовать render features.

Подключаем URP, вешаем сферу на один слой, крест на другой, открываем ассет forward renderer, в transparent layer mask убираем слои объектов. Добавляем 2 render feature.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В layer mask укажите свои слои для объектов.